# How can I add a new option to an inherited tkinter Frame class?

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter

I would like to add a new option to my tkinter Frame inherited class. That option would be `photos` and has to be a list of URLs. The problem is when I pass this option to my tkinter Frame inherited class, Python is raising a error saying the option is not available for that widget.

The call is the following:

```
self.photos = [url1, url2, url3]
self.slideshow_photos = SlideShow(self, width=320, photos=self.photos)
```

And my class is the following:

```
class SlideShow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master

        self.grid()

        self.photos = []
        for photo in kwargs.get('photos', []):
            self.photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(urlopen(photo).read()))))

        self.label_photo = tkinter.Label(self, image=self.photos[0])
        self.label_photo.photo = self.photos[0]
        self.label_photo.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

My first idea was to not pass `*args, **kwargs` to the `Frame.__init__` but then when I pass the other Frame options, like `width`, of course it doesn't take this option into account anymore.

My second idea was to get the option in `**kwargs` and delete from it before calling the `Frame.__init__` but I don't see this as the best way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use kwargs not only in the for photo loop but also pass it to the **init** of tkinter.Frame in

```
tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
```

For tkinter.Frame photos is not a valid keyword argument and therefore the whole thing fails. A potential solution would be

```
class SlideShow(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None,photo_urls=[], *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.master = master

        self.grid()

        self.photos = []
        for url in photo_urls:
            self.photos.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(urlopen(url).read()))))

        self.label_photo = tkinter.Label(self, image=self.photos[0])
        self.label_photo.photo = self.photos[0]
        self.label_photo.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Make however shure that your code works also for an empty list of photos.